# Infinite loop in socket not breaking

Tags: python, sockets, while-loop

I am trying to find out why the loop is not breaking up, but instead it just stuck in prompt. Am I missing something really easy and stupid or is it because my current setup?

Doing just simple socket communication between two points.

Server sending data I need and host received them, but script from some reason not finished.

```
buffer = ''

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    recv_dec = data.decode('utf-8')
    if recv_dec:
        buffer += recv_dec
        print(buffer)
    else:
        break
```

I thought that logic should be right, or ?

By stuck mean, asking prompt or how this step called:
[image]

Sorry btw, I am really begginer.

Comment: Does the other program close the socket? If the other program doesn't close the socket, this program just keep waiting for more data.

Comment: And what do you mean with "just stuck in prompt"? What is the sending code doing?

Comment: yeah, server is still running and waiting for signal to send another data (so socket is still open). So does it mean that I need to recreate a new socket every time ? I hoped that the server can run and just socket will be created when I need.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yeah tried that way too but result was same.

Comment: Exactly what you need to do, in the server and in the client, depends on the protocol you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> help(socket.socket.recv)

recv(...)
    recv(buffersize[, flags]) -> data
    
    Receive up to buffersize bytes from the socket.  For the optional flags
    argument, see the Unix manual.  When no data is available, block until
    at least one byte is available or until the remote end is closed.  When
    the remote end is closed and all data is read, return the empty string.
```

By default `recv` will wait forever for more data to come or until the socket is closed on the other end. So it's not that your loop is looping forever it's that it's stuck waiting for data to be sent from the server. To make `recv` return immediately if no data is available use the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag (or equivalent, maybe depending on your operating system). You might now run into the problem that `recv` returns prematurely with no data because it's reading faster than the server is writing but that's the gist of it.

Comment: eeh, it is not exactly what I wanted to hear :/. And I guess there is not a normal (or easy for beginner) way to keep server listening and let other python scripts create socket connections when I need. Or any idea ?

Comment: That's usually done using multiple threads, if I understand your question correctly. It's not too difficult to understand how it's done but more than can be explained in a comment here. Try a web search for "python tutorial tcp client server" and that should point you in a helpful direction.